# delete catalina.*.log older than 30 days using logrotate

Tags: tomcat, logrotate

I am looking for ways to use logrotate to delete "catalina.*.log" which is older than 30 days.
By default catalina.log is rotating daily. I would like to know the procedure to delete these files older than 30days using logrotate and not using a script.

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult and obscure for `catalina` logs due to how Tomcat rotates them itself. I think a script is best, but it can be a one-liner 'script' cron job.

```
find /path/to/catalina/logs/catalina.*.log -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Run it once a day.

Comment: I tried this, but it deletes all catalina.log files including current ones.
/app/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.18/logs/catalina.*.log {
daily
rotate 2
missingok
}

Comment: Updated - catalina logs look to be a bit of a pain.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I will end up using script. Would have been nice if there is some option using logrotate. I will keep checking..